# Error with opening a filehandle

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have just begun working with Perl, I am only at the introductory level, and I have been having trouble with opening filehandles.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$proteinfilename = 'peptide';

open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename) or die "Can't write to file '$proteinfilename' [$!]\n";

$protein = <PROTEINFILE>;

close PROTEINFILE;

print $protein;

exit;
```

Every time I tried to run the program, it gave me an error

`readline() on closed filehandle PROTEINFILE at C:\BIN\protein.pl`

or

```
Can't write to file 'peptide' [No such file or directory]
```

Can you please help me figure this out.  I have the file **peptide saved as a** `.txt` and its in the same folder as the **protein.pl**.  What else can I do to make this work?

Comment: Is the file called "peptide" or "peptide.txt"? How are you running the script? The location of the script isn't necessary your working directory when it's run.

Answer (score 4):

You're telling `perl` to open file `peptide` in the current directory, but it doesn't find such a file there ("No such file or directory").

Perhaps the current directory isn't `C:\BIN`, the directory in which you claim the file is located. You can address that by moving the file, using an absolute path, or changing the 
current directory to be the one where teh script is located.

```
use Cwd        qw( realpath );
use Path::File qw( file );

chdir(file(realpath($0))->dir);
```

Perhaps the file isn't named `peptide`. It might actually be named `peptide.txt`, for example. Windows hides extensions it recognises by default, a feature I HATE. You can address this by renaming the file or by using the correct file name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to open the file for reading or writing?  Your `open` statement opens it for reading; your error message says 'writing'.  You use it for reading — so your error message is confusing, I believe.

If you get 'No such file or directory' errors, it means that despite what you thought, the name 'peptide' is not the name of a file in the current directory.  Perl does not add extensions to file names for you; if your file is actually `peptide.txt` (since you mention that it is a 'txt file'), then that's what you need to specify to `open`.  If you run `perl protein.pl` and `peptide` (or `peptide.txt`) is in the current directory, then it is not clear what your problem is.  If your script is in `C:\BIN` directory and your current directory is not `C:\BIN` but `peptide` (or `peptide.txt`) is also in `C:\BIN`, then you need to arrange to open `C:/bin/peptide` or `c:/bin/peptide.txt`.  Note the switch from backslashes to slashes.  Backslashes have meanings specific to Perl as an escape character, and Windows is happy with slashes in place of backslashes.  If you must use backslashes, then use single quotes around the name:

```
my $proteinfilename = 'C:\BIN\peptide.txt';
```

It may be simplest to take the protein file name from a command line argument; this gives you the flexibility of having the script anywhere on your PATH and the file anywhere you choose.

---

Two suggestions to help your Perl:

1. Use the 3-argument form of `open` and lexical file handles, as in:

   ```
   open my $PROTEINFILE, '<', $proteinfilename or
       die "Can't open file '$proteinfilename' for reading [$!]\n";

   my $protein = <$PROTEINFILE>;

   close $PROTEINFILE;
   ```

   Note that this reads a single line from the file.  If you need to slurp the whole file into `$protein`, then you have to do a little more work.  There are modules to handle slurping for you, but you can also simply use:

   ```
   my $protein;
   { local $/; $protein = <$PROTEINFILE>; }
   ```

   This sets the line delimiter to `undef` which means the entire file is slurped in one read operation.  The `$/` variable is global, but this adjusts its value in a minimal scope.  Note that `$protein` was declared outside the block containing the slurp operation!
2. Use `use strict;` as well as `-w` or `use warnings;`.  It will save you grief over time.

I've only been using Perl for 20 years; I don't write a serious script without both `use strict;` and `use warnings;` because I don't trust my ability to spot silly mistakes (and Perl will do it for me).  I don't make all that many mistakes, but Perl has saved me on many occasions because I use them.

Comment: I don’t much like to see people autorecommending autovivved handles when that isn’t where the querent’s problem lies. It distracts them from fixing the real bug, whatever it is. And if you are going to use three arguments, where is the encoding?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added in the C:\user\BIN extension to the peptide file when naming $proteinfilename and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here how your program will go

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $proteinfilename = 'peptide.txt';

open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename) or die "Can't write to file '$proteinfilename' [$!]\n";

my $protein = <PROTEINFILE>;

close PROTEINFILE;

print $protein;
```

**You need to add the file extension(for example .txt) at the end like below.**

```
my $proteinfilename = 'peptide.txt';
```

**Your program say `peptide_test.pl` and input text file `peptide.txt` should be in the same directory.**
If they are not in the same directory, use absolute path like below.

```
my $proteinfilename = 'C:\somedirectory\peptide.txt';
```

Note: Use single quotes in case of absolute path.This will ignore the backslash`\` in path.

Now about errors, If you don't use `die` statement, you will get error

```
readline<> on closed filehandle PROTEINFILE at C:\BIN\protein.pl
```

After using die,

`or die $! ;`

you will get error `No such file or directory.`

Also  always

```
use strict;  
use warnings;
```

-w is deprecated after `perl 5.6`. These two lines/statements will help you finding **typos,syntax errors**

And one more,I don't think you need `exit;`, at the end.
[Refer exit function.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, got the program to work as you mentioned